# Why my code in js do not working? Why the function problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have task on programming course. I need to add color to div pixels, but my code doesn't work, even though I think I'm doing everything right.

```html
<div class="container">
      <h1>Pixel art</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="palette">
          <h2>Palette</h2>
          <span class="item color1"></span>
          <span class="item color2"></span>
          <span class="item color3"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="picture">
          <h2>Picture</h2>
          <div class="pixels">
            <!-- Bring the drawing here -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```js
let itemNode = document.querySelectorAll(`.item`);
let pixelsNode = document.querySelector(`.pixels`);

let color1 = document.querySelectorAll(`.color1`);
let color2 = document.querySelectorAll(`.color2`);
let color3 = document.querySelectorAll(`.color3`);

function onClick (evt) {
    let node = evt.target;
    pixelsNode.innerHTML += node;
}

itemNode.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

Tell me to a beginner, please)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My code just do not work, i do not understand why. Please help me figure it out.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a list of nodes. `itemNode` cannot work on the list, you need to either iterate through the list and attach to each item or maybe better use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation).